# When I use biblatex to print bibliography, how can I make in-text citations as "author (year)" instead of "author year"?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

My codes are:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letter, twoside]{article}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Bibliography (References)
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, cytestyle=authoryear, sorting=nyt]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{references.bib} %Imports bibliography file

\begin{document}

\section{Argument}
\cite{acemoglu} argues that inclusive political institutions are crucial for economic development.

\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc, type=article, title={References}]

\end{document}
```

In my bibliography file "references.bib", there exists a literature recorded in standard bibtex syntax that indicates its citation in text as "acemoglu". I want the citation in text to look like "Acemoglu (2012) argues that....", but LaTeX gives me "Acemoglu 2012 argues that ....". I don't think that the latter is an appropriate format for a paper. So, I wonder if there is a way to fix it with biblatex.

Answer (score 2):

According to the `biblatex` manual `\cite` produces a citation without parenthesis. When the authors/editors are meant to flow in the text, the command is `\textcite` (if the `natbib` compatibility option is enabled, `\citet` is available).